How to I correctly type a tuple whose length changes based on a function argument?
I have a function for generating test data that looks like this:
interface User {
    person: string;
}
declare function createUser(): Promise<User>;

async function generateTestUsers(userCount = 2): Promise<User[]> {
  // Generate users
  const result: User[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < userCount; i++) {
    const user = await createUser();
    result.push(user);
  }
  return result;
}

Calling functions then destructure the users from the array returned from the function:
should('do something with some users', async () => {
  const [user1, user2] = await generateTestUsers(2);
  // Do the test
});

This works fine, however there's nothing to stop a careless developer changing the value of userCount without changing how many users they're destructuring from the array.
Is there a way for generateTestUsers to instead return a tuple with the correct number of elements, based on the value passed to the function?

That's just an array. Can't you loop over it instead of destructuring it?

• You might want to make sure you've got a [mre] (your const result: User[] should be initialized, and you should probably define User and related things for us so we're all on the same page). • If someone calls generateTestUsers() with a negative or non-integer or unexpected input, TS can go a little nuts dealing with these "tuple of length" types. One possible approach is as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate source. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz I'm afk at the moment but that example looks exactly like what I want to achieve! Thanks. Yes the example is very brief but I wanted to make sure that the bits relevant to the question weren't lost in the noise of input sanitation etc.

I mean that something like interface User { prop: string } and declare function createUser: Promise<User>; should be in there. Could you edit that or something like that in, when you get a chance? And of course tell me if the suggested solution works for you or not.

Ah I see what you mean. I've just tried your solution and can confirm it works, so thank you again!

No problem. I linked to a few similar questions above (essentially it's "how do I get a tuple of generic length N") which do it a few different ways.
